# Terminate piped program when it asks for input

Tags: winapi, pipe

When using pipes to read from spawned processes, is it possible to terminate said program when it asks for input?

If it doesn't terminate, the usual ReadFile loop until the pipe is closed will block forever:

```
tsi.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
tsi.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
tsi.hStdInput := hInputRead;
tsi.hStdOutput := hOutputWrite;
tsi.hStdError := hErrorWrite;

if not CreateProcess(nil, PAnsiChar(Cmd), @sa, @sa, true, 0, nil, PAnsiChar(WorkDir), tsi, tpi) then
    exit;

// Close handles we don't need. We are only interested in its output
CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);
CloseHandle(hInputRead);
CloseHandle(hErrorWrite);

repeat
    // ReadFile will never return while our programs waits for input
    if not ReadFile(OutputRead, Buf, SizeOf(Buf), nRead, nil) or (nRead = 0) then
    begin
        if GetLastError = ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE then
            Break
        else
            ErrFunc('Pipe read error, could not execute file');
    end;

    // do something with buf...

until False;
```

Terminating by itself is quite easy (just use TerminateProcess), but one only knows when to call TerminateProcess when its too late, i.e. when it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're not using pipes in the Win32 sense, you're using redirected console output.
That being said, however, you can [wait on the file handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and abort if the wait times out.